# Ionic: Unable to stack li vertically

Tags: css, ionic-framework

Following is code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-40">
        <ul class="">
            <li class="payment-type">Visa</li>
            <li class="payment-type">Mastercard</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="col-60">60</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.payment-type {
    background-color: lightgray;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 50px;
}
```

[image]
AS you can see it only shows *Visa* rather both divs. The desired result is to to make a box like `li` with certain padding.

Comment: By default `li` should stack vertically [Here](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/Nxjjoy?editors=110) is how the code that you provided looks. You might have other styles applied that are impeding with the `li`

Comment: @AntonioSmoljan This is why I mentioned `ionic` specifically.

Comment: can u make rough picture..and update the ques...how u want to look this..!i had try this code..and i m able to see both "li".!