# Can I replace Ionic CSS with Bootstrap css?

Tags: android, css, twitter-bootstrap, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic first time for Android App and also post a question([Ionic: Unable to stack li vertically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34677569/ionic-unable-to-stack-li-vertically)).

Thing is, Ionic's CSS is bothering and not giving desired result. As suggested in link posted above.

Will it be OK if I discard Ionic's CSS and implement bootstrap's CSS only? technically it is possible. Has anyone do it? What issues could be if I don't call `ionic.css` file?

Answer (score 1):

If you discard ionic's css most of it's niceties(widgets etc) will break. You want to override it as needed. I have had success using parts of angular-ui-bootstrap and other libraries that depend on bootstrap in Ionic apps. Have a look at this discussion: https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-twitters-bootstrap-css-framework-again/8269